# How do I find words in Blender online manual?

Tags: documentation

Looking for a manual that I can search and find words. 
A big pdf book.  Or instructions on how to find words within the online manual. Or maybe   I have visited the online manual many times now and used search and found nothing relevant.
Does the online manual for blender have an index someplace.   Can anyone recommend a nice book that has a large searchable pdf file?

Comment: I usually just search from a search engine and type "blender manual" before the topic I want to know about. It usually leads me to exactly the manual page I needed.

Comment: Or similarly use the site keyword for google `site:/www.blender.org/manual/ nla`  will give you a list of links containing nla

Comment: site:/www.blender.org/manual/ nla is new to me   THX

Answer (score 1):

The bad news: The Blender manual does not have an effective search function - also in parts it has gaps and in parts information can be improved.

[image]

The good news: If you can find your way through the menu's it is actually packed with tons of useful information. [or use google as has been suggested]

I still use the manual for refence, but mostly rely on the internet and sites like this. There are some good books out there - for example [Packt Blender Books](https://www.packtpub.com/all?search=blender), but the problem for most books is that a new version of Blender has come out by the time they are published.